# Android - Null pointer exception in a constructor variable

Tags: java, android, adapter

I'm working on a custom adapter for a grid view in an android application. It is defined as follows:

```
public class BoardAdapter  extends BaseAdapter {

public static final int EMPTY = 0;
public static final int RED = 1;
public static final int BLACK = 2;
public static final int RED_PROMOTED = 3;
public static final int BLACK_PROMOTED = 4;


Context context;
int[][] board = null;


public int[] pieces = new int [64];
{
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
            {
    //null pointer exception here           
                if(board[i][j] == RED)
                {
                    pieces[8*i+j] = R.drawable.red_piece;
                }
                else if(board[i][j] == BLACK)
                {
                    pieces[8*i+j] = R.drawable.black_piece;
                }
                else pieces[8*i+j] = 0;
            }
        }
};


public BoardAdapter (Context ctx, int[][] board)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    this.board = board;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pieces.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pieces[pos];
}

@Override
public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setImageResource(pieces[pos]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
    return imageView;       
}
```

}

I create the object in the onCreate method of the activity:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);  
    board = (GridView) findViewById (R.id.board);
    game.printBoard();
    //null pointer exception here
    board.setAdapter(new BoardAdapter(this, game.getBoard()));

}
```

When I print the board, the log displays the correct values. So I am sure, that I pass an initialized board to the BoardAdapter constructor. I have no idea, why at the object creation it throws a null pointer exception when referring to this array's element...

Comment: what is `game.printBoard();`

Comment: npe => post stacktrace

Comment: yes, board is null. How is that a surprise ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the you wrote a `initializer`  block and using board which is null.

```
public int[] pieces = new int [64];
```

//you are started a `block` here.MIND that the `board` not yet initialized.

```
{
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
            {
    //null pointer exception here           
                if(board[i][j] == RED)
                {
                    pieces[8*i+j] = R.drawable.red_piece;
                }
                else if(board[i][j] == BLACK)
                {
                    pieces[8*i+j] = R.drawable.black_piece;
                }
                else pieces[8*i+j] = 0;
            }
        }
};
```

What you do is create a method called intializer and do there

```
public int[] pieces = new int [64];
private void intialize(){

{
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
            {
    //null pointer exception here           
                if(board[i][j] == RED)
                {
                    pieces[8*i+j] = R.drawable.red_piece;
                }
                else if(board[i][j] == BLACK)
                {
                    pieces[8*i+j] = R.drawable.black_piece;
                }
                else pieces[8*i+j] = 0;
            }
        }
}

}
```

and now call that method in constructor.

```
public BoardAdapter (Context ctx, int[][] board)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    this.board = board;
    intialize();
}
```

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski glad it helped.ppeterka66 also gave another solution  possible for your problem.See that edit and mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the order of processing

```
...
int[][] board = null; // this.board value assigned as null

public int[] pieces = new int [64]; //defining value, doesn't matter now

//WARNING this is an instance initializer block! Gets to run before the code of the constructor...
{ 
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
//null pointer exception here           
            if(board[i][j] == RED) //access stuff that does not exist...
            {
                pieces[8*i+j] = R.drawable.red_piece;
            }
            else if(board[i][j] == BLACK)
            {
                pieces[8*i+j] = R.drawable.black_piece;
            }
            else pieces[8*i+j] = 0;
        }
    }
};
```

...

Somewhere *in the future* the constuctor would be called

```
  ...
  this.board = board; //board is assigned a value
  ...
```

**EDIT**

`I want to assign the values of a 2 dimensional array board into a one-dimensional array pieces, so that I can get the appropriate images for the grid elements`

Then you should create a method to accomplish that, and not a static initializer block (assuming the voard is always 8 by 8, and is not null):

```
public int[] getPieces()
{ 
    int[] pieces = new int[64];
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<8;j++)
        {
            if(board[i][j] == RED)
            {
                pieces[8*i+j] = R.drawable.red_piece;
            }
            else if(board[i][j] == BLACK)
            {
                pieces[8*i+j] = R.drawable.black_piece;
            }
            else pieces[8*i+j] = 0;
        }
    }
    return pieces;
};
```

And call this on BoardAdapter instance whenever you'd like.

Comment: Make work what? What do you want to achieve? Do you want to populate the pieces array from the elements of the board received in the constructor?

Comment: I want to assign the values of a 2 dimensional array board into a one-dimensional array pieces, so that I can get the appropriate images for the grid elements

Comment: Create a method and do there and call that method after the initialization finished. PS Am not a android guy.

Comment: @ppeterka66 I think initialization is enough I guess.No need to return,Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski Updated the answer to provide a method to get the 1d array.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Depends on what he wants to do. If he wants to apply changes to the 2d array, and retrieve the updated 1d array each time, he'd need the method. If he does not want to do that, the initializer is enough - but then he doesn't need to store the 2d array - but this is a bit of guessing...

Comment: @ppeterka66 Yes that is also a point.Anyways now Michal have two option's to choose,which he wants.Upvote from my side.